# Javascript map method creating 'Object doesn't support this property or method ' in Internet Explorer (IE)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

javascript code shows  error  in Internet Explorer but not in FF.

```
$(document).ready(function(){




var countries = [
  ["Afghanistan","Af"],
  ["Åland Islands","Ax"],
  ["Zimbabwe","Zw"]
];

 var countryNames = countries.map(function(country){
  return {
    /*label: '<div class="flag '+country[1].toLowerCase()+'">'+country[0]+'</div>',*/
    value: country[0]
  }

  var my_var=countryNames();
}); 

});
```

In IE 8 developer tool, if I debug js, the error message is :' Object doesn't support this property or method'. And the error is indicated at the snippet starting with the line :

```
var countryNames = countries.map(function(country){
```

How to make the code work in IE ?

Comment: Which version of Internet Explorer are you using? According to the [MDN entry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for the Array `map()` function, it's only supported in IE9.

Comment: IE8, I need to make the code work for all IE except IE6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function is only supported in Internet Explorer 9, so that code won't work in earlier versions of the browser. Since you've tagged the question as jQuery, you could use the [jQuery.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) function instead:

```
var countryNames = jQuery.map(countries, function(country) {
    return { 
        value: country[0]
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/anthonygrist/DsJsL/) tested using Internet Explorer 9 in IE7 mode.

Answer (score 1):

Use Jquery .each() instead http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

```
var countryNames = [];    
$.each(countries, function(index, value){
    countryNames.push(value[0]);
}
```

Comment: If they're going down the jQuery route, why not use [jQuery.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)?

Answer (score 0):

Not all versions (if any) have `Array.prototype.map`

This is a polyfill/MonkeyPatch you can use to support it under IE -- but including this code may cause problems if you use `for ... in` on your arrays.

[Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference%2FObjects%2FArray%2Fmap)

Answer (score 0):

```
  var my_var=countryNames();
});
```

should be:

```
}); 
  var my_var=countryNames;
```

Worked in IE9 for me.

Or you can you use $.each like Neil Kennedy said.

Comment: The `countryNames` variable references an array, not a function, so that line can be removed entirely because it just throws an error.