# Object doesn't support property or method 'map' - IE11

Tags: vue.js, internet-explorer-11, typeahead

I'm using a Typeahead control searching on a password in Vue which works with no issue and no error in modern browsers, but when testing in IE11 I get the error: 'Object doesn't support property or method 'map''.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript map method creating 'Object doesn't support this property or method ' in Internet Explorer (IE)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12491444/javascript-map-method-creating-object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add the following javascript script before using the map method (add the script in the head of the index.html page):

```
// Production steps of ECMA-262, Edition 5, 15.4.4.19
    // Reference: http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.19
    if (!Array.prototype.map) {

      Array.prototype.map = function(callback/*, thisArg*/) {

        var T, A, k;

        if (this == null) {
          throw new TypeError('this is null or not defined');
        }

        // 1. Let O be the result of calling ToObject passing the |this|
        //    value as the argument.
        var O = Object(this);

        // 2. Let lenValue be the result of calling the Get internal
        //    method of O with the argument "length".
        // 3. Let len be ToUint32(lenValue).
        var len = O.length >>> 0;

        // 4. If IsCallable(callback) is false, throw a TypeError exception.
        // See: http://es5.github.com/#x9.11
        if (typeof callback !== 'function') {
          throw new TypeError(callback + ' is not a function');
        }

        // 5. If thisArg was supplied, let T be thisArg; else let T be undefined.
        if (arguments.length > 1) {
          T = arguments[1];
        }

        // 6. Let A be a new array created as if by the expression new Array(len)
        //    where Array is the standard built-in constructor with that name and
        //    len is the value of len.
        A = new Array(len);

        // 7. Let k be 0
        k = 0;

        // 8. Repeat, while k < len
        while (k < len) {

          var kValue, mappedValue;

          // a. Let Pk be ToString(k).
          //   This is implicit for LHS operands of the in operator
          // b. Let kPresent be the result of calling the HasProperty internal
          //    method of O with argument Pk.
          //   This step can be combined with c
          // c. If kPresent is true, then
          if (k in O) {

            // i. Let kValue be the result of calling the Get internal
            //    method of O with argument Pk.
            kValue = O[k];

            // ii. Let mappedValue be the result of calling the Call internal
            //     method of callback with T as the this value and argument
            //     list containing kValue, k, and O.
             mappedValue = callback.call(T, kValue, k, O);

            // iii. Call the DefineOwnProperty internal method of A with arguments
            // Pk, Property Descriptor
            // { Value: mappedValue,
            //   Writable: true,
            //   Enumerable: true,
            //   Configurable: true },
            // and false.

            // In browsers that support Object.defineProperty, use the following:
            // Object.defineProperty(A, k, {
            //   value: mappedValue,
            //   writable: true,
            //   enumerable: true,
            //   configurable: true
            // });

            // For best browser support, use the following:
            A[k] = mappedValue;
          }
          // d. Increase k by 1.
          k++;
        }

        // 9. return A
        return A;
      };
    }
```

More detail information, please refer the [Array.prototype.map() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Besides, you could also try to add the following script in the head of the index.html page.

```
 <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/6.23.0/polyfill.min.js'></script>
```

If still not working, can you post enough code to reproduce the problem in a sample, it might be easier for us to narrow down the problem.